# Scanf won't execute for second time

Tags: c, scanf, goto

I am trying:- To re-read the value if user enters an invalid value. But the problem is `scanf()` executes only once and won't execute any other time and programs gets stuck with an infinite loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
main()
{
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b = pow(2,M-1);
    unsigned int c;
    int x;

    printf("b = %i",b);

    input:
    fflush(stdin);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("\nEnter any integer: ");
    x = scanf("%u",&a);

    printf("%u",a);
    if(x==0) 
        goto input;

    printf("\na = %i",a);

    c = a & b;

    printf("\nc = %i",c);

    if(c)
        printf("\nthe bit %i is set",M);
    else
        printf("\nthe bit %i is not set",M);
}
```

I've tried using adding space before `%u` and also tried `fflush(stdin)` but nothing worked.

EDIT: I know that the use of goto is not recommended but I have to do it this way. (Using loop is not an option). M is a macro which I define using the gcc command line at compile time.

Comment: you can use do while loop in this case. Please see the modified code given below

Answer (score 10):

Caution:  `fflush(stdin);` may be undefined behavior. Read: [Why `fflush(stdin)` is wrong?](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1052863818&id=1043284351)

> **`int fflush(FILE *ostream);`**
>   The `ostream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the
>   most recent operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any
>   unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment
>   to be written to the file; otherwise, the `behavior` is `Undefined`.

You can try a loop and read until `EOF` or `\n` given [this FAQ entry](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044873249&id=1043284392) instead of `fflush(stdin)` as I have suggested below in my answer.

Edit: thanks to @[Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler):

> There are platforms where `fflush(stdin)` is fully defined (as a non-standard extension on that platform). The primary example is a well-known family of systems known collectively as Windows.  Microsoft's specification of [`int fflush( FILE *stream );`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx) **If the `stream` is open for input, `fflush` clears the contents of the buffer**.

I have additional doubt in your code; what is `M` in expression `unsigned int b = pow(2,M-1);`? It should be an error if you don't define it. Are you posting complete code?

**Regarding you logic of error detection:**

> re-read the value if user enters an invalid

No, `scanf()` does not return an error code. It returns the number of successful conversions.

> [int scanf ( const char * format, ... );](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)
>   **Return Value**
>   On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match
>   the expected number of items or *be less (even zero) due to a matching
>   failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.*
>
> **If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while
>   reading, the proper indicator is set (`feof` or `ferror`). And, if either
>   happens before any data could be successfully read, `EOF` is returned.**
>
> **If an encoding error happens interpreting wide characters, the
>   function sets `errno` to `EILSEQ`.**

So actually depending on the error encountered the return value may be zero, EOF. You should use [`int ferror ( FILE * stream );`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ferror/) and [`errno`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cerrno/errno/) macro for error detection (check the example given at link).

Errors possible because of *invalid input* can be:

> `EILSEQ`: Input byte sequence does not form a valid character.
>   `EINVAL`: Not enough arguments; or format is NULL.
>   `ERANGE`: An integer conversion would exceed the size that can be stored in the  corresponding integer type.

Check [scanf manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) for complete list.

**Reason for infinite loop:**

The system keeps track of which input has been seen so far.  Every call to `scanf` picks up from where the last one stopped matching input.  This means that if an error occurred with the previous `scanf`, the input it failed to match is still left unread, as if the user typed ahead.  If care isn't taken to discard error input, and a loop is used to read the input, your program can get caught in an infinite loop.

So for example in your code:

```
x = scanf("%u", &a);
      //   ^
      //  need a number to be input
```

But suppose you don't input a number but an invalid string is entered e.g. `"name"` (instead of a number, as you say). This will cause the `scanf()` function to be fail when attempting to match an unsigned integer (`"%u"`), and the word `"name"` is left unread.  So the next time through the loop, the `scanf()` doesn't wait for fresh user input, it tries to convert "name" again.

Similarly if the input were `29.67`, the "`%u`" will match the first two characters only (the `29`), leaving the `.67` as unread input for the next call to `scanf()`.

Even if the input is correct, as `29`, the newline that ended the input is still left unread.  Normally that isn't a problem since most conversions automatically skip leading white-space such as the trailing newline from the previous line.  However some conversions (`"%c"` and `"%["`) don't skip any leading white-space, so you have to do it manually.

**To avoid this infinite-loop One suggestion:**

(remember: as I recommended the use of `ferror()`, error-value is preferable to detect invalid input. Additionally, it's just for learning purpose and if you need to implement a serious application you should use `fgets(str)` instead of `scanf()` followed by that parse `str` input to verify whether input is valid)

```
input:
    //fflush(stdout); //use if needed, as \n used in printf no need of fflush-stdout
    printf("\nEnter any integer: ");
    x = scanf("%u", &a); // always wait for new symbols
    printf("%u", a);

    if(x == 0){ // x=0, if error occurred
        // read all unread chars 
        while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
        goto input;
    }
```

It's just a suggestion that will possibly work with your code (worked for me, your code + gcc). But if you use this technique incorrectly it may leave a bug in your code:

Read [How do I flush the input buffer?](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044873249&id=1043284392)

> If you are sure that unwanted data is in the input stream, you can use
>   some of the following code snippets to remove them. However, if you
>   call these when there is no data in the input stream, the program will
>   wait until there is, which gives you undesirable results.

Comment: +1 for this --*You can try a loop and read until EOF or \n*, it clearly outlines that OP should banish the use of `goto` :)

Comment: Grumble: this is too strong!  There are platforms where `fflush(stdin)` is fully defined (as a non-standard extension on that platform).  The primary example is a well-known family of systems known collectively as Windows.  See Microsoft's specification of [`fflush()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx): **If the stream is open for input, `fflush` clears the contents of the buffer.**

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok! now I can remind In past with turbo-C under DOS in university I had use `fflush(stdin)`. And that was not wrong! ~~ Thanks!

Comment: @Coffee_lover read [this answer on `scanf()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831060/store-data-in-array-from-input?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround to avoid infinite loop.
Instead of goto please use do while loop:

```
do {
     printf("\nEnter any integer: ");
     x = scanf("%u",&a);

     printf("%u",a);
     if( x == 0)
     {
          char c;
          printf("hit any key \n");
          c = getchar();
     }

   } while(x==0);
```

Comment: stev, `x` is assigned a value returned by scanf(),  it scanf dosn't scan a value it returns 0, read: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: Grijesh, Yes, I missread his question.   scanf won't return EOF unless the input stream is closed - that would be that the console closes. So it runs into infinite loop.