# Store data in array from input

Tags: c, arrays

I'm beginner in C. Please dont mind if my question is lame. In this program which i have written, when I use 'for' loop first time , I expect only 3 values is stored in an array but it stores 4 values and in next 'for' loop as expected show 3 values. 
My Question is why in 1st 'for' loop it takes 4 values instead of 3?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int marks[3];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a no\n");
        scanf("%d\n",(marks+i));
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",*(marks+i));
    }
}
```

Comment: `void main` is not legal. Use `int main`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\n` in `scanf` was the problem

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int marks[3];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a no\n");
        scanf("%d",(marks+i));
    }

    printf("\nEntered values:\n");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",*(marks+i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Reason:**

> I expect only `3` values is stored in an array but it stores 4 values
>   and in next 'for' loop as expected show 3 values. My Question is why
>   in 1st 'for' loop it takes 4 values instead of 3?

**First:**  No, it only stores `3` number but not `4` numbers in array `marks[]`.

**Second:** interesting to understand loop runs only for three times for `i = 0` to `i < 3`. The for loop runs according to condition. More interesting code is stuck in `scanf()` as described below:

Your confusion is why you have to enter four numbers, its not because you loop runs `4` times but its because `scanf()` function returns only when you enter a non-space char (and after some <kbd>enter</kbd> press you inputs a number symbol that is non-space char).

To understand this behavior read manual: [`int scanf(const char *format, ...);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html):

> A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see
>   `isspace(3)`). This directive  **matches any amount of white space,
>   including none, in the input**.

Because in first for loop's, in  `scanf()` you have included `\n` in format string, so `scanf()` returns only if press  a number <kbd>enter</kbd> (or a non-space <kbd>key</kbd>).

```
 scanf("%d\n",(marks+i));
           ^
           |
            new line char
```

What happens?

Suppose input to program is:

```
23        <--- because of %d 23 stored in marks[0] as i = 0
<enter>   <--- scanf consumes \n, still in first loop
543       <--- scanf returns, and leave 542 unread, 
                               then in next iteration 543 read by scanf in next iteration
<enter> 
193
<enter>  <--- scanf consumes \n, still in 3rd loop
<enter>  <--- scanf consumes \n, still in 3rd loop
123      <--- remain unread in input stream
```

Comment: thanx DX but when i used \n after %d in scanf, it takes 2 values first time when value of i is 0 but when value of i becomes 1 and 2 it takes only 1, why this happens?

Comment: please go through this http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110801122000AA07FO8   hope this gives you the exact reason

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan sure it will be helpful for all :) Please do

Comment: read from [`int scanf ( const char * format, ... );`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) in **Parameters**/ if format string is a **Whitespace character:** itd return *`A single whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including none).`*  So when @ranaarjun use `\n` in scanf it always wait to read a `\n` even after last number enter, and because `\n` can consume any number of `\n` as I quote to until **OP** don't enter a non-while char (he actually entered number then) scanf don't leave reading from input-stream

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan nice and healthy explanation :) thanks

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes it will be good if you put the same explanation in a new answer since you have explained it better you should be getting the rps for the explanation

Comment: @SanyamGoel always remember that fflush(stdin) is an undefined behavior ..... we all are here to learn :)

Comment: Yes this explains in the most easy way thanks :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; Nice explanation. I like specially last part of this answer.

Comment: @haccks Thanks! did you read this [Scanf won't execute for second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827603/scanf-wont-execute-for-second-time?lq=1) I explained scanf in much depth

Comment: @haccks , SanyamGoel,  PHIfounder : To understand scanf and printf One should read [C Printf and Scanf Reference](http://wpollock.com/CPlus/PrintfRef.htm)

Answer (score 0):

remove `\n`
and `i` can be created in the if statement as `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {}`