# How to expect different data types in scanf()?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm developing a chess game in C just for practicing. At the beginning of the game, the user can type 4 things:

- ROW`<whitespace>`COL (i.e. `2 2`)
- 'h' for help
- 'q' to quit

How can I use a `scanf` to expect 2 integers or 1 char?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the line, and then trying to use two different `sscanf`s on it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It helps to show us what you've got, so we can build upon that.

Comment: This answer:[Store data in array from input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831060/store-data-in-array-from-input?lq=1) will be helpful for you I think so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like it would be most sensible to read a whole line, and then decide what it contains. This will not include using `scanf`, since it would consume the contents `stdin` stream.

Try something like this :

```
char input[128] = {0};
unsigned int row, col;
if(fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin))
{
    if(input[0] == 'h' && input[1] == '\n' && input[2] == '\0')
    {
        // help
    }
    else if(input[0] == 'q' && input[1] == '\n' && input[2] == '\0')
    {
        // quit
    }
    else if((sscanf(input, "%u %u\n", &row, &col) == 2))
    {
        // row and column
    }
    else
    {
        // error
    }
}
```

Comment: In the case you read just 1 byte from stdin, you are then accessing uninitialized variables and you're in UB. Quick solution for this is just to initialize the input array

Answer (score 5):

It's better to avoid using `scanf` at all. It usually causes more trouble than what it solves.

One possible solution is to use `fgets` to get the whole line and then use `strcmp` to see if the user typed 'h' or 'q'. If not, use `sscanf` to get row and column.

Comment: @RodrigoAlves Go search how to use functions `fgets`, `sscanf`, etc. Make some toy programs using them. I'm sure it doesn't take much effort for you to master them.

Comment: `fgets` can't get the whole line in one call reliably. Of course, in this case it's not an issue, since we don't need more than 3 characters anyway, but in different situation it could be a problem.

Comment: @Joker_vD : What's stopping you from calling `fgets` and expanding your buffer until you hit a newline?

Comment: @Joker_vD If you mean `fgets` may only get part of the line, because it has be specify the maximum characters to read, that's actually a good thing, comparing to `gets`, `fgets` won't cause buffer overflow. But you are right to be careful with this fact.

Comment: @YuHao  Congrats on your 10K :) You are one rapidly scorer!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Thanks. Hopefully I'll keep active, I really enjoyed the community of SO.

Answer (score 0):

This one is just using scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char c;
        int row, col;
        scanf("%c", &c);
        if (c == 'h')
                return 0;
        if (c == 'q')
                return 0;
        if (isdigit(c)) {
                row = c - '0';
                scanf("%d", &col);
                printf("row %d col %d", row, col);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar This code looks like it should work.  It should accept two digits separated by a space.  Remember scanf reads per format statement, it is NOT bound to read a complete line. +1.

Comment: @SakthiKumar : A normal one, yes. A one in a computer game can be much larger. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int row, col;
char cmd;

char *s = NULL;
int slen = 0;
if (getline(&s, &slen, stdin) != -1) {
    if (sscanf(s, "%d %d", &row, &col) == 2) {
        free(s);
        // use row and col
    }
    else if (sscanf(s, "%c", &cmd) == 1) {
       free(s);
       // use cmd
    }
    else {
       // error
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, indeed. It turns out all our C projects where I work include an old utility file which provides `getline()`. The realization that `stdio` can't just read a line in one piece and return it really upset me.

Comment: +1 I used the `IFs` and `sscanf` solution together with @Daniel's answer

Answer (score -2):

P.S.: those who did not read and understand my answer carefully, please respect yourself, DO NOT VOTE-DOWN AT WILL!

Beside "get the whole line and then use sscanf", read char by char until '\n' was entered is also a better way. If the program encountered 'h' or 'q', it could do the relevant action immediately, meanwhile you cloud also provide a realtime analysis for the input stream.

example:

```
#define ROW_IDX 0
#define COL_IDX 1
    int c;
    int buffer[2] = {0,0};
    int buff_pos;
    while( (c = getchar())) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            //a line was finished
            /* 
            row = buffer[ROW_IDX];
            col = buffer[COL_IDX];
            */
            buff_pos = 0;
            memset(buffer , 0 , sizeof(buffer));//clear the buffer after do sth...
        } else if (c == 'h') {
            //help
        } else if (c == 'q') {
            //quit
        } else {
            //assume the input is valid number, u'd better verify whether input is between '0' and '9'
            if (c == ' ') {
                //meet whitespace, switch the buffer from 'row' to 'col'
                ++buff_pos;
            } else {
                buffer[buff_pos%2] *= 10;
                buffer[buff_pos%2] += c - '0';
            }
        }
    }
```