# Reading different input from scanf - C language

Tags: c, string, file-io, input, scanf

I have a question about reading input from scanf.

The user enters one of two commands. Either a single worded command, or a two worded command separated by one space.

For example:

start

OR

begin program

I am trying to read from scanf. But I have a problem. If I do `scanf("%s", input);` I am assuming he will enter only the one worded command.

If I do `scanf("%s %s", input1, input2);` I am assuming he will enter a two worded command. But if he enters a one worded command, then the scanner will continuously consume white space until a different character is read.

For the two worded command I want to store each word in a separate string variable.

Please help.

Comment: What is exactly Your aim/problem ? You do not know, what the user does and want to react to either option properly ?

Comment: Note that you may use scanf("%s", &input), i.e. with the adress operator.

Comment: @PhillipD; It is not sure either `input` is pointer variable or just a variable.

Comment: Use fgets() and then sscanf(). Note that both scanf and sscanf return the number of variables parses.

Comment: @haccks Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Remove space in format string, change:

```
scanf("%s %s", input1, input2);
```

as

```
scanf("%s%s", input1, input2);
```

To understand this behavior read manual: [`int scanf(const char *format, ...);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html):

> A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see
>   `isspace(3)`). This directive  **matches any amount of white space,
>   including none, in the input**.

So because of the space after first `%s` the scanner continuously consume white space until a different character is read.

Read: ["C Printf and Scanf Reference"](http://wpollock.com/CPlus/PrintfRef.htm) good tutorial.

Related Question: If you are interested read also ["Store data in array from input"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831060/store-data-in-array-from-input) question and answer it will help your further.

Comment: When I read the question, I thought he was talking about how to parse one or two strings without knowing what was in the input.

Comment: @CharlieBurns Read linked answer and my reference to scanf and printf ..I sure you like that.

Comment: This wasn't what I was looking for. Charlie burns is right, I do not know whether the input is two words or one.

Comment: Your answer assumes that it is already a two word answer. When I try to enter a one word command it waits for me to put in another character before it continues.

Comment: @user2817240 See I given you the reason of how your `scanf()` behaving  and why? What exactly you wanted to ask is unclear. either post a new question. or ask in comment.

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out. Look at Chuck Cottrill's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, read the first word, and then conditionally read the second word,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char cmd[100];
    char cmd1[100],cmd2[100];
    printf("enter command:"); fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%s",cmd1);
    printf("%s\n",cmd1);
    if( strncmp(cmd1,"begin",strlen("begin"))==0 ) {
        printf("read second word\n");
        scanf(" %s",cmd2);
    }
    else strcpy(cmd2,"none");
    printf("%s,%s\n",cmd1,cmd2);
}
```

results,

```
$ ./scanf2 
enter command:start
start
start,none
$ ./scanf2 
enter command:begin command
begin
read second word
begin,command
```

Comment: I prefer fgets and then sscanf or strtok to parse input.

Comment: @user2817240 Good that you find answer, now you may like to [accept this answer by click on right-mark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) preferable way to say thanks is by voting up :)