# loop executes more than needed

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "commonf.h" //So, this is the way you include from a directory?
void main(){
    println("Welcome to Number Guesser v 0.1 ");
    println("Think of a number between 0 and 100 (and please, make it an integer!)");
    println("Legend: Y=Yes B=Bigger than that S= Smaller than that");
    int guessed=0;
    float curnum=100.0;
    char cursign='?';
    while(cursign!='y'){
        if(cursign=='?' || cursign=='s'){
            curnum=curnum/2;
        }
        else if(cursign=='b'){
            curnum=curnum+curnum/2;
        }
        else{
            printf("You are wrong. Stop it. %c .  TEESST",cursign);
        }
        char askstring[4096];
        sprintf(askstring,"%s%f%s","Is your number ",curnum," ? (y/b/s)");
        println(askstring);
        scanf("%c",&cursign); //Scanf has to expect a new line for some reason.
    }
}
```

(I pasted all of it, since I am a c noob)

If the code looks like this, the loop will execute twice per user input, once with cursign= to whatever the user entered, and once with it equal to \n.

If I change the scanf line to

```
scanf("%c\n",&cursign);
```

It asks for the first input twice, then works as a charm. What's the problem, and what should I do?

Comment: Read [Store data in array from input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831060/store-data-in-array-from-input?lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this `scanf("%c\n",&cursign);` to this `scanf(" %c",&cursign);`. This will eat up the trailing newline character.

Also as per standard `main` should return an `int` (even though this is not the reason for your problem). According to C standards main should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`

When you enter a character like `y` and hit the ENTER key, a character (which you entered) and a character (which is the enter keystroke - the newline character) gets placed in the input buffer. The first character gets consumed by the `scanf` but the newline remains in the input buffer so what happens is that the next time you enter something there 3 characters `newlinechar + 'y' + newlinechar`. So that makes `scanf` behave funny.

This is a great link from Grijesh -  [C Printf and Scanf Reference](http://wpollock.com/CPlus/PrintfRef.htm)

Comment: That fixed it. Can I have an explanation as to why the whitespace should be before the %c, not after it?

Comment: @user2534511 Yes because `in format string a sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see isspace(3)). This directive matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input.` Actually your loop not running infinite or more  times!!!

Comment: @user2534511 I marked a link with your question read Q&A there.

Comment: @Acme according to C standards main should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - Thanks for completing that part :)

Comment: @Acme Actually add in your answer, Here is a good source of learning [C Printf and Scanf Reference](http://wpollock.com/CPlus/PrintfRef.htm)

Comment: @user2534511 - Sorry i was away from my system, see my edits.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - Thank you again, sure i will modify my answer.