# In C,Print Statement not getting Printed in for loop

Tags: c, function, io

In my program, after I enter the first input. I expected the values to get printed because of the `printf` statement next to `scanf`, but for the first time alone it's not getting printed.For the next iterations and all its working correctly

Ex:

Output :
Enter input10
12
i=0,a[i]=11896224
Enter input

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int func(int *, int);
int *a;
int main()
{
    int length = 5;
    a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*length);
    for (int i = 0;i < length;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter input");
        scanf("%d\n", &a[i]);//100,104,108,112,116
        printf("i=%d,a[i]=%d\n", i, &a[i]);/*Print Statement which is not executing for first time*/
    }
    func(a, length);
    return 0;
}

int func(int *b, int length)
{
    printf("Length=%d", length);
    for (int j = 0;j < length;j++)
        printf("b[%d]=%d", j, b[j]);//
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you'll find that scanf doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird scanf behaviour when reading number and newline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828797/weird-scanf-behaviour-when-reading-number-and-newline)

Comment: Side notes: (1) [Don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/3488231), and (2) It may be preferable to use [`size_t`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2550774/3488231) or `ssize_t` for lengths.

Comment: @Smac89 its a bit similar but not exactly the same,For me only for the first iteration the problem occurs ,for the remaining trials its working fine

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `\n` from the `scanf` function.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer ,I found your  article in the following url "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443483/using-n-in-scanf-in-c",  Can you suggest the reason for this problem

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but it has something to do with whitespaces in the buffer, which is ignored by `scanf` or something as such.