# Checking of Newline char in input

Tags: c, matrix, newline

Code:

```
printf("Enter your data (5x10) of characters: \n");
for (i = 0; i < SIZE1; i++)
for (j = 0; j < SIZE2; j++)
    scanf("%c", &matrix2[i][j]);
compress(matrix2);
break;
```

My code is suppose to take in a `5 x 10` matrix of char. But currently my newline is being input into the matrix, how do I actually check for the newline char, and prevent it from going into `matrix2[i][j]`?

It reads a total of 4 newline char. 
Input:

```
aaabbbcccd (press enter)
ababababab (press enter)
bcdbcdbcdb (press enter)
ababababab (press enter)
abbbcccdda
```

Comment: Read [Store data in array from input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831060/store-data-in-array-from-input?lq=1)

Answer (score 6):

You can add a space before your `%c` specifier, like this

```
scanf(" %c", &matrix2[i][j]);
```

The blank space here in the format string is telling [`scanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) to skip any leading whitespace or newline character, thus consuming the next character typed with the %c conversion specifier.

Your situtation is happening because when you `(press enter)`, the next `scanf()` call is consuming this newline character `\n` that was left behind, therefore making your statement fail.

Answer (score 4):

Add a space:

```
scanf(" %c", &matrix2[i][j]);
       ^
```

The space (unintuitively) consumes any white-space, including the `\n`. But this change means you can't put a space into `matrix`, which may or may not be what you want.

But it is generally better to use e.g. `fgets()` and `sscanf()` rather than `scanf()` to parse input.

Comment: but suppose if OP use fgets then space chars will be stored in matrix[], I think you should suggest first read input in a buffer then parse it to store in matrix[]

Answer (score 2):

```
char matrix2[SIZE1][SIZE2];
int ch, count, end, i, j;
char  *p = &matrix2[0][0];

printf("Enter your data (5x10) of characters: \n");
count = 0; end = SIZE1 * SIZE2;
while (EOF!=(ch=fgetc(stdin)) && count < end){
    if(ch == '\n')
        continue;
    p[count++] = ch;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can store the i/p character in a dummy variable and then check if it is a space or a /n .
ie.

```
printf("Enter your data (5x10) of characters: \n");
for (i = 0; i < SIZE1; i++)
for (j = 0; j < SIZE2; j++)
{
  d:  scanf("%c", &a);
      if(a!=' '||a!='\n')
          matrix2[i][j]=a;
      else
          goto d;
}

compress(matrix2);
break;
```