# How to ignore floating number in scanf("%d")?

Tags: c, scanf

If user enters floating number for an integer variable I want to print invalid input. is that possible?

```
 int a;
 scanf("%d",&a); // if user enters 4.35 print invalid input
```

I have tried for characters like this

```
  if(scanf("%d",&a)==1);
  else printf("invalid input");
```

But how to do for floating numbers. If user enters `4.35` it truncates to `4` but I want invalid input.

Comment: Maybe take in a float, then check if it stays the same after rounding?

Comment: Linked again: [Scanf won't execute for second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827603/scanf-wont-execute-for-second-time/17827635#17827635) I think related posts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the start of a floating point number with any digits before the decimal point looks like an integer, there is no way to detect this with `%d` alone.

You might consider reading the whole line with `fgets()` and then analyzing with `sscanf()`:

```
int a;
int n;
char line[4096];
if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0 && sscanf(line, "%d%n", &a, &n) == 1)
   ...analyze the character at line[n] for validity...
```

(And yes, I did mean to compare with 1; the `%n` conversion specifications are not counted in the return value from `sscanf()` et al.)

One thing that `scanf()` does which this code does not do is to skip blank lines before the number is entered.  If that matters, you have to code a loop to read up to the (non-empty) line, and then parse the non-empty line.  You also need to decide how much trailing junk (if any) on the line is tolerated.  Are blanks allowed?  Tabs?  Alpha characters?  Punctuation?

Comment: Isn't this a bit overcomplicated?

Comment: It depends on what you want. Using `fgets()` and `sscanf()` is generally better than `scanf()`; it will be a whole heap easier to report on what the user typed this way. So, factor that out of the solution. That leaves `sscanf(line, "%d%n", &a, &n) == 1` and checking that you don't have a decimal point (default `.`, but locale-specific in general), or an `e` or `E` as the next character; anything else means the value entered was an integer. Even the `E` is not strictly proof; you'd need to see `E` and a number. 1.2E is the number 1.2 with an E after it, AFAIK (though I've not tested it today).

Comment: Interesting: on an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative, the following code regards the `E` as part of the floating point number; it prints out the space (32) as the stopping point. `#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) { char data[] = "34.1E and junk"; double d; int n; if (sscanf(data, "%lf%n", &d, &n) != 1) printf("scan failed\n"); else printf("Got: %f (stopped at '%c' %d)\n", d, data[n], data[n]); return 0; }` I'm not completely convinced that's correct behaviour; on Mac OS X, the conversion stops on the `E` instead (correct by my reckoning). (`"34.1E- and junk"` stops at blank on Linux too.)

Comment: Actually, prior to C99, its unspecified whether the match for `%n` is counted in the return value -- so a successful match might return 2 on some systems.  That's ok as you can easily catch this case by using `sscanf(line, "%d%n", &a, &n) >= 1` instead as a failure to match will always return 0.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: interesting — I wasn't aware of that detail (or not any more; it is a while since I worked in an environment which was not reasonably C99 compliant).

Comment: @ChrisDodd: ISO 9899:1990 for `%n` in `fscanf()` says: _No input is consumed. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to integer into which is to be written the number of characters read from the input stream so far by this call to the `fscanf` function. Execution of a `%n` directive does not increment the assignment count returned at the completion of the `fscanf` function._ Thus, only pre-standard versions of `fscanf()` could count `%n` (and `%n` was added by the C89 standard, AFAIK — though there probably was some prior art). Unless you think Schildt made up the standard in his book.

Comment: @thejh robust I/O in C is complicated !

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to read it as a double and then check if it is an integer. The best way to check if it is an integer is to use [modf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/), which returns the decimal portion of the double. If there is one you have an error:

```
double d;
scanf("%lf", &d);

double temp;
if(modf(d, &temp)){
  // Handle error for invalid input
}

int a = (int)temp;
```

This will allow integers or floating point numbers with only `0`s after the decimal point such as `54.00000`. If you want to consider that as invalid as well, you are better off reading character by character and verifying that each character is between `0` and `9` (ascii 48 to 57).

Comment: Does not one need to check for range, should `d` be outside `int` range?

Comment: On many 64-bit machines, an `int` with 64 bit range exceeds the precision of a double, thus scanning the incorrect value into 'a'.  A `long double` _may_ work though.

Comment: Not many 64-bit machine use a 64-bit `int` size; it leaves you with a quandary about what to do with 32-bit integers (or 16-bit integers).  However, if you were dealing with `long long` (or 64-bit `long`), then your point would be entirely valid.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler The range of an `int` may _usually_ be within the  integer representable range of a `double`.  But "usual" is not portable idea.  I prefer portable ideas and this solution had a weakness concerning that.  I've worked in embedded where `double` and `float` are the same.  That would limit this solution even if `int` was still 32-bit.

Answer (score 3):

This can not be done with out reading pass the `int` to see what stopped the scan.

Classic idiom

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeo(buf), stdin) == NULL) {
  ; // deal with EOF or I/O error
}
int a;
char ch;
if (1 != sscanf(buf, "%d %c", &a, &ch)) {
  ; // Error: extra non-white space text
}
```

Comment: If there's white space after the integer, it was an integer.  If the user typed `34 .34` (with a space before the `.`), they typed a valid integer first; there's just trailing junk after it on the line.  Of course, that might be what you're after...any trailing junk is an error.  It isn't clear from the question.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  "34 .34" would fail the above as the extra, IMO, negates the correctness of the input.  As you say, OP did not specify about trailing/leading white space nor extra text.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `strtol()` and `strtod()` and comparing the end pointers, e.g. this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char buffer[100];
    char * endptr_n;
    char * endptr_d;
    long n;
    double d;

    fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
    n = strtol(buffer, &endptr_n, 10);
    if ( endptr_n == buffer ) {
        fputs("You didn't enter a number.", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    d = strtod(buffer, &endptr_d);

    if ( *endptr_d == '\0' || *endptr_d == '\n' ) {
        if ( endptr_d == endptr_n ) {
            puts("You entered just a plain integer.");
        } else {
            puts("You entered a floating point number - invalid.");
        }
    } else {
        puts("You entered garbage after the number - invalid.");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

outputs:

```
paul@local:~/src/c$ ./testint
2
You entered just a plain integer.
paul@local:~/src/c$ ./testint
2.3
You entered a floating point number - invalid.
paul@local:~/src/c$ ./testint
3e4
You entered a floating point number - invalid.
paul@local:~/src/c$ ./testint
4e-5
You entered a floating point number - invalid.
paul@local:~/src/c$ ./testint
423captainpicard
You entered garbage after the number - invalid.
paul@local:~/src/c$
```

It doesn't use `scanf()`, but that's a good thing, and it avoids the need to manually check the input following the integer you read.

Obviously, if the only thing on the line is the number, then a lot of this becomes unnecessary, since you can just call `strtol()` and check `*endptr_n` immediately, but if there may be other stuff on the line this is how you can do it, e.g. if you want to accept an integer followed by anything non-numeric, but not a floating point followed by the same thing, you can just remove the `if ( *endptr_d == '\0' || *endptr_d == '\n' )` logic.

EDIT: updated the code to show the check to `*endptr`.

Answer (score 1):

This one is bit easier:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int a;
    long double b;

    scanf("%f",&b);
    a = (int) b;

    a == b ? printf("%d\n",a) : printf("Invalid input!");

    return 0;
}
```

Input: 4
Output:

```
4
```

Input: 4.35
Output:

```
 Invalid input
```

Comment: On _many_ machines, if 'b' > 16,777,216, the scan of text into a float loses precision that would not occur had a `int` been read directly.

Comment: Unclear on "bit" in `unsigned long long bit`.  Please clarify.

Comment: @chux; Oops! Its `unsigned long long a;`.

Comment: If "16777217" was entered, `b` would likely get the value 16,777,218.0.  If 'a' was `int` or `unsigned long long`, the wrong value would be assigned for the limitation is in the `float`, not `a`.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan I posted an answer and commented on candidate improvements in others.  What improvements are you suggesting?

Comment: @chux actually I was attending more then one posts, And I notice very answer here are very interesting (didn't vote any one yet). I need to read again sincerely.

Comment: @haccks A `double` may be sufficient in most cases, but `long double` is better if available.  In any case, both better than a `float`.

Comment: Note: This causes undefined behaviour if user inputs a float out of range of `int` (or whatever integer type you use)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int d;
    printf("Type something: ");

    // make sure you read %d and the next one is '\n'
    if( scanf("%d", &d) == 1 && getchar() == '\n' ) {
        printf("%d\n", d);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

.

```
$ a.exe
Type something: 312312.4214

$ a.exe
Type something: 2312312
2312312

$ a.exe
Type something: 4324.

$
```

Comment: Show some test cases! Did you try?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is nothing wrong with `scanf`.  When a user enters a float then they actually type in a number dot number.  So, code a scanf to detect that data entry.

```
main()
  {
       char c1[2];
       int num1;

       int nr_nums;

       nr_nums = scanf("%d%1[.e0123456789]", &num1, &c1);

       if (nr_nums == 1) {printf("\ndata = %d", num1);}
       if (nr_nums == 2) {printf("\nInvalid");}

 }
```

Modified this code per another possible data entry format of 1. or 3e-1 as suggested by a comment.

This code gets to the basics of your requirement.  It accepts Integer data entry and detects when a float is entered.

Comment: This won't work if they enter a floating point number using scientific notation, though, e.g. `1e-5`, and writing `1.` without anything to the right of the decimal point is a perfectly legitimate way of writing floating point constants in C, and someone may input it like that expecting it to be recognized.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, the question was if the user entered n.m not your example.  I will think about your requirement and figure out out scanf can be modified accordingly.  I.e. different requirement, different answer!

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, have modified the code to handle the possibilities that you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your number represented as a string (when you have used fgets) you can run a for loop through it and compare each character to '.'.

Answer (score -1):

One other option I can see follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{

 char mystring[31];
 scanf("%30s[0-9]\n", mystring);
 int mynumber = atoi(mystring);
 printf("here is your integer: %d", mynumber);
 getchar();
 getchar();
 return 0;











 }
```

Comment: This does not work. An entry of, e.g. `12.34` reports that an integer value of 12 has been entered, but OP wants such inputs to be considered invalid. You may find a solution by looking into [`strtol()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.4). Also note that there is no need for `#include <string.h>` here.

Comment: This still does not work. Have you tried this code? There are some significant problems here: the `s` is not part of the scanset directive, so the format string should be `"%30[0-9]"`. Trailing whitespace characters should (almost) never be used in `scanf()` format strings; they cause havoc with interactive input and do not do what most people think they do here. As it is, with `"%30s[0-9]\n"`, only the `%30s` is matched. Even with the corrections, input of `12.34` is still incorrectly treated as an input of 12.