# Accept Numerical Values only for input using scanf

Tags: c, scanf, numerical-methods, numerical

How can I make sure the user inputs numerical values only instead of alphanumeric or any other character? Also what to look for to insert error message for incorrent input?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a, b, c;


   printf("Enter first number to add\n");
   scanf("%d",&a);

   printf("Enter second number to add\n");
   scanf("%d",&b);

   c = a + b;

   printf("Sum of entered numbers = %d\n",c);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you enter other then numeric value while format string is `%d` then scanf will throws an error, use returned value of scanf(), read: [Scanf won't execute for second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827603/scanf-wont-execute-for-second-time/17827635#17827635)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to deal with user input that could be hostile **use a separate function** for getting the number.

Allows
- leading spaces             : "  123"
- trailing spaces            : "123   "
- leading zeros              : "0000000000000000000000000000000000123"
- Rescans nicely after error input.
Catches the following errors
- No input                   : ""
- Extra text after the number: "123 abc"
- Text before the number     : "abc 123"
- Split number               : "123 456"
- Overflow/underflow         : "12345678901234567890"
- other                      : "--123"
Re-prompts on invalid input.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int GetInteger(const char *prompt, int *i) {
  int Invalid = 0;
  int EndIndex;
  char buffer[100];
  do {
    if (Invalid)
      fputs("Invalid input, try again.\n", stdout);
    Invalid = 1;
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
    if (NULL == fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin))
      return 1;
    errno = 0;
  } while ((1 != sscanf(buffer, "%d %n", i, &EndIndex)) || buffer[EndIndex] || errno);
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  int a, b, c;
  if (GetInteger("Enter first number to add\n", &a)) {
    ; // End of file or I/O error (rare)
  }
  if (GetInteger("Enter second number to add\n", &b)) {
    ; // End of file or I/O error (rare)
  }
  c = a + b;
  printf("Sum of entered numbers = %d\n",c);
  return 0;
}
```

---

BTW, You should *not* do `printf("Enter first number to add\n")`.  Use `fputs()` instead.  Consider what would happen if the string had a `%` in it.

Comment: @user2741667 Added the necessary `#include` files.  Code compiles without syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to avoid using `scanf` at all. Use `fgets` to get entire line, and then use `sscanf` to extract the information you need. Check the return value of `sscanf` to make sure the input is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the manual page for [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf). You need to check the return value. SHould return 1 if able to match a number.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT-** I needed to add the `getchar()` in the while loop because the unread non-numeric item was left in the input queue causing the program to go in an infinite loop , further I have also added more compact form of `while` loop for the same thing , both will have the same effect .

You can check the return value of `scanf` it returns 1 on successful match with the format specifier and 0 if not . You can do it like this for your program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(void)
{ 
  int num;
  bool status;//_bool may also be used and stdbool.h won't be needed for that

  status = scanf ("%d",&num);

  if (status != 1 )
    {
      getchar();// needed to add it to eat up the unread item left in input queue.
      while (status != 1)
        {
          printf (" sorry ! incorrect input :ERROR: try again");

          status = scanf("%d", &num);

        }
    }
  /*....do something...*/
  return 0;
}
```

**More compact form of while loop** :-

```
while (scanf("%d",&num) != 1)
    {
      getchar();
          printf (" sorry ! incorrect input :ERROR: try again\n");
    }
```

**Besides,** you should always use meaningful names for variables like `num1` and `num2` for instance instead of `a` and `b` .