# How do I get scanf in C to print an error when a char is detected?

Tags: c, scanf

This is what I think the code should look like. It's inside a function (main) by the way.

```
char a;
if (a [is detected]) {
    printf("Incorrect input format \n");
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

Comment: What is the correct format you expect to have?

Comment: I'm expecting int integers only.

Comment: better way is first read in a buffer then parse it to validate, if you wants to use `scanf` read [Scanf won't execute for second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827603/scanf-wont-execute-for-second-time/17827635#17827635)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that digits are *also* characters. What you want to do is to use `scanf` to scan for an integer, and check the return value. The return value from the `scanf` family of function is the number of successfully scanned items, or `-1` on error. If you scan for a single integer (format `"%d"`) then if `scanf` doesn't return `1` there was an error.

So you could do something like

```
if (scanf(" %d", &number) == 1)
{
    /* Got a number okay */
}
else
{
    /* Not a number in the input */
}
```

Also remember that if `scanf` fails, the input is still there, so you can't just loop and hope the current input will be disregarded. A simply way to get by that is to use `fgets` to read one line of input, and then use `sscanf` to scan the newly read line.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fread`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) instead of `scanf` to read the input from `stdin`. Parse the input provided by user to check if `char` is given as input, then print the error.

Comment: At this time, I'm only experimenting with scanf. Once I master it, I'll move on to other things.