# Print an "Error" statement after do-while loop in C

Tags: c, loops, do-while

How could I print a message telling the input is wrong after a do-while loop? Or am I using a wrong loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main(){
    int inp;
    do{
        clrscr();
        printf("Enter Number < 10: ");
        scanf("%d",&inp);
    }
    while(inp>10); // Print "Wrong" when inp>10
    printf("Right Answer!");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Just add an if statement after the scanf.

Comment: you could add `&& printf(error)` to your while statement in order to avoid the extra check but hey...

Comment: If you wants to validate user input..I have suggested in this answer, Read [Scanf won't execute for second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827603/scanf-wont-execute-for-second-time/17827635#17827635)

Comment: And, while you're checking the inputs, don't forget to check that `scanf()` didn't report problems.  You need `if (scanf("%d", &inp) != 1) { ...handle error... }` or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do one of two things:

Add an extra check to the end of your while loop:

```c
if(inp>10){
    printf("error");
}
```

or you can avoid the extra check, while sacrificing a bit of readability and change your while 
loop to

```c
while(inp>10 && printf("error"))
```

This works because if the first statement if true, the `printf()` will not be executed due to short-circuiting, but if it is false, the `printf()` will be executed before the return to the top of the loop.

Comment: +1 for "*...sacrificing a bit of readability ...*" in this very case.

Comment: This really helps to solve the question, but my real code uses a prototype function and doesn't work