# While-loop response to multiple conditions in C

Tags: c, while-loop, conditional-statements

Here I have a code that should print "Error" **after** the first sequence of the loop, since according to my previous question [Print an "Error" statement after do-while loop in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674208/print-an-error-statement-after-do-while-loop-in-c/19674298#19674298) It would only read the first condition of the loop due to "*short-cicuiting*" and would only be executed after the first sequence of the loop... After solving that I still can't display "Error!", so I tried adding `&& getch()` that gave me an output of

```
Error!
```

Now that I have 3(*Multiple*) conditions that caused the "Error!" to be executed within the first sequence, I want to know **how does C respond to my multiple conditions**, that might help me to solve the error.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main(){
    int inp;
    while(inp<10 && printf("Error") && getch()){
        clrscr();
        printf("Enter Number > 10: ");
        scanf("%d",&inp);
    }
    printf("Right Answer!");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Why are you putting the `printf` and `getch` in the while-condition? They would be much more suited in the body.

Comment: The `printf("Error")` will be cleared by `clrscr()` and it return non-zero value always expect `printf("")` so it is irrelevant to while condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int inp;` is not initialized. Also `main` should return `int`. Automatic variables are not initialized to a default value. Testing `inp<10` like this is undefined since `inp` can be any junk value.

This is all you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int  main(){
    int inp = 0;
    while(inp<10 && printf("Error\n") )
    {
        printf("Enter Number > 10: ");
        scanf("%d",&inp);
    }
    printf("Right Answer!");
    getchar();
}
```

`conio.h` is not part of the C standard library. But as said by unwind in comments the above code will print `Error` unnecessarily once - you can redesign your code to something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int  main(){
    int inp = 0;
    while(1 ) // always true
    {
        printf("Enter Number > 10: ");
        scanf("%d",&inp);
        if(inp<10 )
            printf("Error\n");
        else
            break; // break out of while loop
    }
    printf("Right Answer!");
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: But this will print "Error" *before* the user has had a chance to enter anything. That's horribly rude.

Comment: Which by the way is my main problem

Comment: @Daniel - Like i said - look at the second snippet - its easier to read as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) for C language if you have `&&`, `||` or `?` in condition it will not evaluate all conditions if it is not necessary see example:

```
if(0 && printf("ERROR!\n"))
  printf("OK\n");
```

Will never print any text because `(0 && whatever)` will evaluate always as false so it will not continue with second condition after `&&` but if you will change position

```
if(printf("ERROR!\n") && 0)
      printf("OK\n");
```

Will print only `ERROR!` because `printf("ERROR!\n")` will print text and return some number greater then zero (7) so condition will be reduce to `(7 && 0)` what will evaluate both conditions as false but will print your `ERROR!` message.

When you have more `&&` operators they will evaluate in Left-to-right order so it will looks like this:

```
if( ( (inp<10 && printf("Error")) && getch() ) && ... )
```

so it will first check if `inp` is less then 10 and only if its is true will continue with printing `Error` and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
    int inp = 0;
    scanf("%d",&inp);


    while(inp<10 && printf("Error") && getch()){
        clrscr();
        printf("Enter Number > 10: ");
        scanf("%d",&inp);
    }
    printf("Right Answer!");
    getch();

   return 0;
}
```

You have to initialize/ assign value to inp before checking in the loop.

Comment: `clrscr();` and `getch();` is not part of the C standard library, ISO C nor is it defined by POSIX.