# How to check that input is number to use in while condition in c programming

Tags: c, while-loop

I actually want to do this.

```
int i;

printf("enter choice:");
scanf ("%d", &i);

while (i>4 || i==0 || i is not an integer)
{  printf("invalid input. enter choice again between 1 to 4: ");
scanf ("%d", &i);}
```

pls help.

Comment: _Hint_: [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns the number of successful assignments made.

Comment: Read [Scanf won't execute for second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827603/scanf-wont-execute-for-second-time/17827635#17827635) I think it will help you.

Comment: This might be useful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099473/how-to-scanf-only-integer-and-repeat-reading-if-the-user-enter-non-numeric-chara)

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: i is always a number. It is an int.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `scanf` gives you the number of items successfully assigned. In this case you have only one, the `%d`, so the return value is either 1 for success or 0 for failure (i.e., the input was not a number) when input is available. If `stdin` is closed or an input error occurs, `scanf` will return `EOF` (a defined constant with a value less than 0).

Comment: It is not true that *the return value is either 1 for success or 0 for failure*. It can be `EOF` if the end of input is reached prematurely, or an I/O error happens. Subtle, yes, but I think it's worth mentioning it because it could lead the OP to have an infinite loop for not testing for `EOF`.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves You are right, I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Please write the full codes. i am not understanding.

Comment: @user3308618 If you do `result = scanf("%d", &i);` where `result` is an `int`, then you can check `if (result > 0) { /* a number was read */ } else { /* error or not a number */ }`

Comment: can you pls tell me how to do it inside the while loop.
I have done this, 
 int i, result;

    printf("enter your choice:");
    scanf ("%d", &i);

    result = scanf("%d", &i);

    while (i>4 || i==0 || result<1)
 {  printf("invalid input\n enter your choice again: ");
      scanf ("%d", &i);}

but the loop does not stop . :(

Comment: @user3308618 Copypaste the code inside a `while` -loop, or use only the `result = scanf(…)` in place of your current `scanf`s and put the `result` check into the condition of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

e.g

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i=0, stat;

    printf("enter choice:");
    stat = scanf ("%d", &i);

    while (i>4 || i<1 || stat !=1){
        if(stat == EOF) return -1;
        printf("invalid input. enter choice again between 1 to 4: ");
        if(stat != 1)
            scanf("%*[^\n]");//skip the bad input
        stat = scanf ("%d", &i);
    }
    printf("your choice is %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the input as string and then convert it to an int :

```
char buf[256];
scanf("%s", buf); // will flush remaining bytes
int i = atoi(buf); // 0 on failure (strtol is safer)
```